# GUI - How to save changes to file automatically?

Tags: python, function, class, user-interface, save

I´ve created two python files - first one that stores main classes and second one   for GUI which uses functions from first one. I also have a file - list of items that I would like to work with - automatically save changes to it everytime I add or delete item in GUI window. I´ve got a problem how to write down two functions for GUI - "add_item" and "delete_item". Add_item is already able to add_item when GUI window is open, however, it is only temporary, cos it doesn´t save changes to file (list of items). I´m beginner in python, so many thanks for any help.

Here is a part of first py-file (that stores classes):

```
    def AddItem(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, Item):
            if item not in self:
                self.append(item)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Item is in class already")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Object from class Item is expected")

    def AddItemWithName(self, name, size, price):
        newItem = Item(name, size, price)
        self.add_item(newItem)

    def DeleteItem(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, Item):
            if item in self:
                self.remove(item)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Item was not deleted")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Object from class Item is expected")

    def DeleteItemWithName(self, name):
        self.delete_tiem(Item(name))

    def SaveToFile(self):
        with open("list_of_items.bin", 'bw') as f:
            pickle.dump(self, f)

    def LoadFromFile(self):
        with open("list_of_items.bin", 'rb') as f:
            self.clear()
            self.extend(pickle.load(f))
```

Here is a problem part from second py-file for GUI:

```
    def add_item():
        try:
            name = input_value1.get()
            size = input_value2.get()
            price = input_value3.get()
            items_class.addItemWithAtributes(name, size, price)
            output_value1.set("Item was added")
        except ValueError:
            output_value1.set("Item was not added")
        items_class.SaveToFile()

    def delete_item():
        try:
            name = input_value4.get()
            #items_class.deleteItemWithAtributes(name)
            output_value1.set("Item was deleted")
        except ValueError:
            output_value1.set("Item was not deleted")
        items_class.SaveToFile()
```

Comment: To save changes to a file, you just need to rewrite the file with the new values included

Comment: Note: When you find that `item` is not an instance of `Item` you should raise a `TypeError`, not a `ValueError`.

Comment: Consider writing to a text file instead and reading the data from that. You may find it easier than trying to write the syntax of Python into the .py file.